# Laravel Tinker error when creating a user - 'User' not found in eval()'d

Tags: php, laravel

When trying to create a user on tinker, i'm presented with this error.

I've never used tinker before so I have no idea what to do.

```
 $ artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.6.1 (PHP 5.5.29 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $user = new User;
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

Any one some across this before.

Update:
Note: i'm using *artisan* as a alias for *php artisan*

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure to include your namespace when in Tinker.

For example

```
$user = new App\User();
```

Where `App` is the namespace

Comment: @DaleSnowdon you may find it easier to google it next time, it was one of the first results for a search with that error over on the [laravel forums](http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-laravel-50-php-artisan-tinker-error)

Comment: It was a copy and paste from a tutorial so I assumed the syntax was correct, my bad.